# PHP Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, http

I am Getting following error "Warning: file_get_contents  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request " while hitting "http://Google.com"

```
 <?php
        $content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
        if (strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")) { 
         echo "SUCCESS";
       } 
       else { 
              echo "FAILED";
            }
   ?>
```

because of this problem i am not able to parse the URL .I am using WAMP(Apache Version-2.2.22,PHP version 5.4.3).

Steps taken :-
1.allow_url_fopen Enabled in php.ini
2.Tried Encoding the URL
3.Even Used Curl php function getting same problem.
4.Allowed Firewall on

Please help.

Comment: Probably they block those obvious non-browsers user agents. You are not supposed to use curl or php to perform google searches after all. Even though a 400 statuscode is pretty odd; i'd expect a 403 in this case.

Comment: Btw, the google "root" URL should read `http://www.google.com/`, with  trailing slash. But again, this should not cause the error 400.

Answer (score 5):

```
$html = @file_get_html($url);   
if($html==FALSE) {
  echo 'error';
} else {
  echo 'success';
}
```

check it this one here $url is www.google.com.then you get the correct result

Answer (score 2):

The request actually succeeds, you have the page in $content. but you make a wrong test for success. The url does not return a 200, but a 302.

Comment: I have modified the code and used 302 as error but getting same result "ERROR"

Comment: Well go and dump that special variable $http_response_header and rethink your test.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it returns status 302 (FOUND)

`echo $http_response_header[0];` // returns 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found'

Answer (score 0):

Some server configurations do not allow opening remote addresses with `file_get_contents` (via `fopen`). 
You might want to change the configuration, but he prefered way to open remote sites (more reliable as well as about 20x faster) is by Using [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl).

A fast and simple example can be found in the PHP docs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#55922)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem with you.
I’m using WAMP on windows 7, until finally I find the solution.

You need to make sure to uncommented the extension=php_openssl.dll at php.ini file in

C:\wamp\bin\php folder. If you setup the openssl via WAMP server menu PHP >> PHP Extention, it won’t affected to the php.exe

Hope this will work for you too.